# Common visa regions

Tags: visas

I learned today that Guatemala, El Salvador, Honduras, and Nicaragua have a Schengen-style common visa region though it is [apparently poorly done](https://wikitravel.org/en/Common_visa).

I looked around some and found something exists or may exist soon for [ASEAN](http://investvine.com/common-asean-visa-system-in-the-making/), and for the [GCC¹ countries](https://www.arabianbusiness.com/gcc-schengen-visa-real-prospect-138203.html).

Are there others?

¹[Gulf Cooperation Council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_Cooperation_Council)

Comment: Theres a [list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_border#List_of_groups_of_states_with_common_open_borders), specifically where it says "Controls on entry to the entire XYZ are carried out at the first country of entry."

Comment: That looks more like an answer than a comment! :-)

Comment: @WGroleau We disapprove of link-only answers. But, hey, we also approve of questions that are "Please give me a big list of data items."

Comment: I guess this is borderline on the “list” point.  But it wasn’t a long list.  :-). I asked because It wouldn’t (didn’t) occur to me to search for “open borders” and the hits on “common visa/travel/tourism/etc. regions” all used “common” as a modifier for “regions” instead of as a modifier for visa/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_border#List_of_groups_of_states_with_common_open_borders), **Regions where you enter once and travel without any further border controls**:

- Schengen (26 European states)
- Common Travel Area (UK and Ireland)
- CA4 (El Salvador, Guatemala, Honduras, Nicaragua) for non-air travel
- Nordic Passport Union (Sweden, Finland, Iceland, Norway, Denmark), now encompassed by Schengen
- Island of Saint Martin (France, Netherlands)

**Schemes where a special visa is valid for multiple countries**

- [East African Tourist Visa](https://www.migration.gov.rw/index.php?id=233) (Kenya, Rwanda, Uganda)
- [APEC Business Travel Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APEC_Business_Travel_Card)

**Schemes that no longer exist**

- Benelux (Belgium, Luxembourg, Netherlands), expanded into Schengen
- CARICOM Special Visa (15 Caribbean countries), coincided with 2007 cricket world cup

Comment: I disagree with adding ASEAN to any list. First, there are border controls between ASEAN countries, so it doesn't belong in the open border list. Second, there's a huge number of country-to-country visa-free policies, if you're adding ASEAN policies, that opens the door to say US-Canada, Hong Kong-China, the entire US VWP, etc.

Comment: Removed GCC as there are border controls and it does not meet the criteria.

Comment: Not sure the Common Travel Area really qualifies, as it allows citizens of either country to travel to the other with "minimal documentation", but visas are actually not valid for both (except the recent BIVS which applies only to a handful of countries). There are also document checks in many cases (though not all).